# Validator Model Driven (Reactive) Forms

Tags: angular

I have a form with an username,a password and a confirm password field. I'm using this validation service to have this two checking s :

1. the password must not contain the username
2. password and confirm password field must contain the same "password"

   ```
   export class ValidationService {


     static getValidatorErrorMessage(validatorName: string, validatorValue?: any) {
       let config = {
         'required': 'Required',

         'invalidPasswordUser': 'Invalid password. Password must not contain the username!',

         'passwordMismatch':'Password mismatch ',
         'minlength': `Minimum length ${validatorValue.requiredLength}`,
         'maxlength': `Maximun length ${validatorValue.requiredLength}`
       };

       return config[validatorName];
     }

    static passwordMatchValidator(control) {

   if (control.value) {


     if (control.value === control.parent.value.password) {

       return null;
     }
     else{

       return { 'passwordMismatch': true};

     }
   }
   ```

   }

   static usernameCheckValidator(control) {

   ```
   if (control.value) {

     if (!control.value.toUpperCase().includes(control.parent.value.username.toUpperCase())) {

       return null;
     }
     else{

       return { 'invalidPasswordUser': true};
     }
   }
   ```

   }
   }

This is the form:

```
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      'username': ['',[ Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4),Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      'password': ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(6),ValidationService.usernameCheckValidator,Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      'confirm': ['', [Validators.required,ValidationService.passwordMatchValidator,Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      'profile': ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
```

Regarding the first check if I write before the username and after the password, it will work in the right way, if the password is not correct(because contains the username) the message will appear. Instead  if in a second time I change the username(e.x I write the password), the password message will not appear. 
Same behavior has the second checking. So,at this moment ,I have something like an "one way" validator.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the validator function on AbstractControl is called when you change the Control itself, meaning that it won't check password when you change the username, it will just check the username.

The solution would be to write the password validation for the username control tot or validation for the Form in general, and there to check the the validations that require other fields. Something like :

```
 formValidation(formGroup){
        if(formGroup.value.password.toUpperCase().includes(formGroup.value.username.toUpperCase()) 
              return {someError:'error'}
    }
```